# How to apply font and color on text in cells of Excel file using openxml

Tags: excel, fonts, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am new in Openxml. I am trying to create a xlsx file using openxml. I want to apply different font and color to the text of different cells in excel file. I am using this for creating a xlsx file but not able to do the font and color part.

```
SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create("E:\\Word9.xlsx", SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

        WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
        workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();


        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());


        Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

        int i = 1;
        while (i <= 5)
        {
            Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = (UInt32)i, Name = "mySheet" + i.ToString() };

            for (int ii = 1; ii <= 5; ii++)
            {

                Row row1 = new Row();
                sheets.AppendChild(row1);

                Cell cll = new Cell(new InlineString(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Text("qqqqqq"))) { DataType = CellValues.InlineString };
                row1.AppendChild(cll);

            }
            sheets.Append(sheet);
            i++;
        }


        workbookpart.Workbook.Save();
```

Is there any one who know how to apply the font and color to different cells?

Answer (score 5):

Like Edward already said you need to create a Stylesheet object.

```cs
var stylesheet = new Stylesheet() { MCAttributes = new MarkupCompatibilityAttributes() {Ignorable = "x14ac"}};
stylesheet.AddNamespaceDeclaration("mc", "http: //schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
stylesheet.AddNamespaceDeclaration("x14ac", "http: //schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac");
```

The Stylesheet object have to contain all Fonts, Fills, CellFormats, etc. that you want use.

```cs
// create collections for fonts, fills, cellFormats, ...
var fonts = new Fonts() { Count = 1U, KnownFonts = true };
var fills = new Fills() {Count = 5U};
var cellFormats = new CellFormats() { Count = 4U };

// create a font: bold, red, calibr
Font font = new Font();
font.Append(new FontSize() {Val = 11D});
font.Append(new Color() { Rgb = "ff0000"});
font.Append(new FontName() {Val = "Calibri"});
font.Append(new FontFamilyNumbering() {Val = 2});
font.Append(new FontScheme() {Val = FontSchemeValues.Minor});
font.Append(new Bold());
// add the created font to the fonts collection
// since this is the first added font it will gain the id 1U
fonts.Append(font);

// create a background: green
Fill fill = new Fill();
var patternFill = new PatternFill() {PatternType = PatternValues.Solid};
patternFill.Append(new ForegroundColor() {Rgb = "00ff00"});
patternFill.Append(new BackgroundColor() {Indexed = 64U});
fill.Append(patternFill);
fills.Append(fill);

// create a cell format (combining font and background)
// the first added font/fill/... has the id 0. The second 1,...
cellFormats.AppendChild(new CellFormat(){ FontId = 0U, FillId = 0U });

// add the new collections to the stylesheet
stylesheet.Append(fonts);
stylesheet.Append(fills);
stylesheet.Append(cellFormats);
```

Assign the Stylesheet to your workbookpart object

```cs
var stylePart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
stylePart.Stylesheet = stylesheet;
stylePart.Stylesheet.Save();
```

After that you are able to assign a CellStyleId to a Cell.

```cs
var cell = new Cell() {
  CellValue = new CellValue("your cooler string"),
  DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String),
  StyleIndex = 0U // index in the cellFormats array
};
```

---

### assigning fonts, fills, borders, etc. to objects like CellFormats

Each `Font`, `Fill`, `Border`, ... can be assigned to other objects by their index in the corresponding collection. For example the first added font to the fonts object will have the index `1U`.

These indices are represented as unsigned integers (no negative values more positive values). The 'U' suffix denotes either a uint or a ulong.

---

### links

[OpenXml docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk), [unsigned integers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/uint)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create and use a style sheet.  Here is a good reference, but there are more if you search on creating a stylesheet.
[Stylizing your Excel worksheets](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chrisquon/2009/11/30/stylizing-your-excel-worksheets-with-open-xml-2-0/)

Comment: link is dead :-(

Comment: Yes, [Chris Quon](https://www.linkedin.com/in/christopher-quon-0080bb39) left Microsoft in 2014 and they recently took down his blog.