# Error adding stylesheet to excel using openXml

Tags: c#, excel, openxml-sdk

I am trying to add styles to the excel file. The plain data gets downloaded correctly in the spreadsheet. But as soon as I add the code for adding stylesheets and not even using any of those styles, it throws error on opening the file -

> Repaired Records: Format from /xl/styles.xml part (Styles)

I have tried including minimal four(default) parameters to the stylesheet- fonts, fills, borders, cellFormats that was a suggestion on the other posts' [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39872791/how-to-apply-font-and-color-on-text-in-cells-of-excel-file-using-openxml) but still couldn't get it fixed.

I would really appreciate help with this.

```
        private void CreateExcelFile(IEnumerable<DataModel> models)
        {
            using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filePath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
                WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
                workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>("rId1");

                worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

                Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());

                Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = "rId1", SheetId = (UInt32Value)1U, Name = "Product Data" };

                sheets.Append(sheet);

                workbookPart.Workbook.Save();

                SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

//below 3 lines need a fix; 
//if I remove these 3 lines, there is no error on opening the excel file
                WorkbookStylesPart stylesPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>("rId3"); 
                stylesPart.Stylesheet = GenerateStyleSheet();  
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.Save();


                Row firstRow = new Row() { RowIndex = 1 };
                firstRow.Append(ConstructCell("Some Message", CellValues.String)); 
                firstRow.CustomHeight = true;
                firstRow.CustomFormat = true;
                firstRow.Height = 100;
                sheetData.AppendChild(firstRow);

                MergeCells mergeCells = new MergeCells();
                mergeCells.Append(new MergeCell() { Reference = new StringValue("A1:E1") });               
                worksheetPart.Worksheet.InsertAfter(mergeCells, worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First());

                var row = new Row(ConstructCell("Some Cell Data", CellValues.String)));

                sheetData.AppendChild(row);

                worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
                document.Close();
            }
        }

        private Stylesheet GenerateStyleSheet() {

            var stylesheet = new Stylesheet();

//tried adding attributes too
            /*
            var stylesheet = new Stylesheet() { MCAttributes = new MarkupCompatibilityAttributes() { Ignorable = "x14ac" } };
            stylesheet.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
            stylesheet.AddNamespaceDeclaration("mc", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
            stylesheet.AddNamespaceDeclaration("x14ac", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac");
           */
            
            var fonts = new Fonts() { Count = (UInt32Value)1U, KnownFonts = BooleanValue.FromBoolean(true) };
            var font = new Font
            {
                FontSize = new FontSize() { Val = 11D },
                FontName = new FontName() { Val = "Calibri" },
                Color = new Color() { Theme = (UInt32Value)1U},
                FontFamilyNumbering = new FontFamilyNumbering() { Val = 2 },
                FontScheme = new FontScheme() { Val = new EnumValue<FontSchemeValues>(FontSchemeValues.Minor) }
            };
            fonts.Append(font);

            var fills = new Fills() { Count = 1 };
            var fill = new Fill();
            fill.PatternFill = new PatternFill() { PatternType = new EnumValue<PatternValues>(PatternValues.None) };
            fills.Append(fill);

            var borders = new Borders() { Count = 1 };
            var border = new Border
            {
                LeftBorder = new LeftBorder(),
                RightBorder = new RightBorder(),
                TopBorder = new TopBorder(),
                BottomBorder = new BottomBorder(),
                DiagonalBorder = new DiagonalBorder()
            };
            borders.Append(border);

            var cellFormats = new CellFormats(
                    new CellFormat() { NumberFormatId = 0, FormatId = 0, FontId = 0, FillId = 0, BorderId = 0 }, // Index 0
                    new CellFormat() { NumberFormatId = 0, FormatId = 0, FontId = 1, FillId = 0, BorderId = 0, ApplyFont = true }, //Index 1 Bold
                    new CellFormat() { NumberFormatId = 0, FormatId = 0, FontId = 2, FillId = 0, BorderId = 0, ApplyFont = true }, //Index 2 Italics
                    new CellFormat() { NumberFormatId = 22, FormatId = 0, FontId = 0, BorderId = 0, FillId = 0, ApplyNumberFormat = BooleanValue.FromBoolean(true) } //Index 3 Date
                    );
            
            
            stylesheet.Append(fonts);
            stylesheet.Append(fills);
            stylesheet.Append(borders);
            stylesheet.Append(cellFormats);
            
            return stylesheet;
        }



        private Cell ConstructCell(string value, CellValues dataType, uint styleIndex = 0U)
        {
            return new Cell()
            {
                CellValue = new CellValue(value),                
                DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(dataType),
                StyleIndex = styleIndex
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After some modifications to the above code, I realized that the problem was in CellFormat - NumberFormatId = 22 and FontId = 2. On setting both these values to 0, the stylesheets worked fine. My code didn't have the corresponding Font and NumberFormat for the assigned values.

Comment: I know this is ancient but thanks for posting this, I was having the same issue where everything but the stylesheet worked.