Set font color of text in Excel's CellValue - OpenXml with C#
I want to change font color of specific cells text, with export using openXML, C#, I am using predefined excel template to fill data and export from my application.
Here is my code, Please help me to set color to specific cell,
I tried Tried Stylesheet, StyleIndex but it is not working for me, with this font color changed to entire sheet.
If I use stylesheet then it applies to entire sheet.
private async Task<MemoryStream> ExportData(MemoryStrean memory, FilterModel filterModel) 
{
 var reqModel= filterModel.reqModel;
 using (SpreadsheetDocument document= SpreadsheetDocument.Open(memory, true))
  {
   IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == "MySheet");
   string relationshipId =    sheets.First().Id.Value;
   WorksheetPart wp = (WorksheetPart)document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
   if (wp != null)
   {
    SheetData sheetData =wp.Worksheet.GetFirstChild <SheetData>(); 
    if (sheetData != null)
    {
    UInt32Value? RowIndex = 2;
    foreach(var des in filterModel.designations) 
    {
    UpdateCell(sheetData, "C", RowIndex, des.Name);
    wp.worksheet.Save(); 
    RowIndex++;
    } 
   document.WorkbookPart?.Workbook.Save();
   }
  }
 }
return memory;
}
private void UpdateCell(SheetData sd, string colName, UInt32 rowIndex, string value, bool isNumber=false)
{
 Cell cellData= new Cell() { CellReference= colName + rowIndex, DataType= isNumber ? CellValues.Number : CellValues.String, CellValue = new CellValue(value)}; 
 Row r= null;
 r = (Row)sd.Elements<Row>().Where (ri => ri.RowIndex== rowIndex).First();
 if (r.Elements<Cell>().Count(cr => cr.CellReference.Value == cellData.CellReference.Value) > 0)
 {
  Cell c = (Cell)r.Elements<Cell>().Where(cr => cr.CellReference.Value == cellData.CellReference.Value).First(); 
  c.DataType =cellData.DataType;
  if (c.DataType == CellValues.SharedString)
  { 
    c.DataType =CellValues.String;
  } 
  c.CellValue = new  CellValue(cellData.CellValue.Text);
 }
}


https://stackoverflow.com/a/53655560/22851022

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77816338/10024425. It's for Word, but the same process applies to Excel.
